# Проверка возвращаемого значения из EditText Android

Tags: android-edittext

Добрый день!
Задача получить числовое значение из EditText и вернуть его.
Сомневаюсь, правильно ли написал проверку числового значения, если EditText пустой.
Вот метод:

```
    private int getEditText(EditText editText){//Возвращает значение из EditText в формате int
    int tmp;
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    if (text.isEmpty()) tmp = 0;
    else tmp = Integer.parseInt(text);

    return tmp;
```

в layout у EditText стоит значение android:inputType="number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем идеал :) В вашу функцию следует отправлять уже готовый текст, взятый из `EditText`

```
//где-то 
getEditText(editText.getText().toString();

//функция
int getEditText(String s);
//если текст есть
if(!s.equals("")){
//возвращаем его в формате int
return Integer.parseInt(s);
}
//иначе
else{
//придумайте сами
}
```

Извиняюсь за термин "функция", я имел ввиду "метод"

**UPD**
Если вам нужен метод с параметром `EditText` на вход, то вот

```
int getEditText(EditText editText){
String text = editText.getText().toString();
if(!text.equals(""))
return Integer.parseInt(text);
else
//если пуст
}
```

Но все же я советую первый метод, так как передавать `EditText` как-то костыльно.

Comment: А не получится nullpointerexception при использовании equals. Если EditText пуст, то его значение будет равно null. И получится, что мы будем сравнивать null c "".

Comment: Нет, если `EditText` пуст, то текст именно `""` Не нравится `equals` попробуйте проверять `length` на 0